# std::for_each over std::set, C++11

Tags: c++, stl, foreach, set, c++11

Iterating over a vector works:

```
std::vector<int> collection = {2, 3, 4, 5435345, 2};
std::for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [](int& i){cout << i << endl;});
```

but not over a set (compile error):

```
std::set<int> collection = {2, 3, 4, 5435345, 2};
std::for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [](int& i){cout << i << endl;});
```

Why can't I iterate over a `std::set` with `std::for_each`?

Bonus question:
Also, I would like to change the `int&` in the lambda's argument to `auto&`, why can't this be automatically deduced?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`std::set<T>::value_type` is `T const`, not `T`; consequently, the argument to your lambda must be a value type (i.e., copy) or `int const&` (and technically, or `int const volatile&`), not `int&`. I.e., this works:

```
std::set<int> collection{2, 3, 4, 5435345, 2};
std::for_each(
    collection.begin(),
    collection.end(),
    [](int const& i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; }
);
```

---

> Bonus question: Also, I would like to change the `int&` in the lambda's argument to `auto&`, why can't this be automatically deduced?

Because the standard says it can't; historically, I believe this was due to overly-complicated interactions between lambdas and concepts (before concepts were removed from the draft). <strike>However, I hear rumors that the first defect reports to the new (C++11) standard will address exactly this, so it's possible that you'll see support for this added to your compiler of choice within the next year or two.</strike> **EDIT**: Oh, look, C++14 now has polymorphic lambdas...

Comment: where did you hear that?  On Herb sutter's blog he mentions that they won't add polymorphic lambda until the concepts problem has been resolved, because they still want to a concepts-like feature in the future.

Comment: lol what a politician. :) so take that out of the answer, will you?

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the bonus question: An "auto" function argument isn't specific to lambdas. You might as well ask why we don't allow *all* functions to be declared as `f(auto x, auto y)`. But that just means that you essentially want to replace all functions by function templates. That was considered not to work well with the existing C++ language and the type system in particular. If you want a function template, there's already an existing syntax and mechanism, and declaring "auto" arguments is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

A dereferenced `set<int>` iterator is a `const int&`.  So you can't pass it as an `int&` parameter without the `const`.  Try either plain `(int i)` or `(const int& i)`.

And that's really not one of the places you're allowed to use `auto`.  I think `auto` only works in a declaration with initializer or as a placeholder for a trailing return type.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate over a set. However, note that since the element in a set its also its key, it cannot be modified. Change your code to take a `const` reference, and use `cbegin/cend` instead, regardless of whether is a set or not when you are not going to modify the elements.